# Comments off the topic of a question

Tags: discussion, comments

I was reading the comments on [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/7114/2422) and got a bit confused as to why JonnyP and travis were talking about Flipside and Motorola when the OP had a Droid Incredible.  Now to be fair had I not been skimming the comments I wouldn't have been confused - but it does seem odd to be discussing a different problem in the comments.  Now the comments there are kinda on-topic to be helpful to someone else (I think?). But if someone were to come across that again - let it go or ask them to move the conversation to chat/start a new post?  I don't mean to be a bully about it and its great that JonnyP is helping travis out but their comments are not helping the OP at all... right?  Please correct me if I'm wrong about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for that particular question it's okay. The issue doesn't appear to be device specific, so the steps JonnyP is suggesting should help both people.

If Travis had opened a new question, we almost certainly would have closed it as a duplicate of this question.

That's not to say that it's okay to hijack someone else's question, but that in this case I don't think it's out-of-bounds.

Comment: Thanks,  I'll remember this for next time :)

Answer (score 1):

My part in that conversation started because travis said that his phone had the same problem as the OP's, so at first I was trying to find a common thread between their two devices. If they were both running ROMs running Sense UI that would suggest that perhaps it wasn't necessarily a hardware-specific issue and those of us trying to help should focus more on their particular firmwares and not just the phones themselves.  When travis said he didn't know I wanted to try to be clear when explaining to him what he needed to know in order to give me a useful answer.

I hope that clarifies my seemingly off-topic comments.  :)

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  I guess my example (your comments) wasn't the best but it was what sparked my question.

Comment: @Daniel - It's cool, it's a valid concern for keeping the community productive.